# How do I show/hide Tables using checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, html

In the example below, I have a jQuery script which will show features of different houses. For example, if the house only has a bedroom, kitchen & study - it will hide the TV Room & garage tables (using .hide() and.show())

I would like to further add functionality so if the checkbox "study" is ticked, it would only show the study table for each house. Likewise, if "study" and "garage" are ticked it would show the garage. If no checkboxes are ticked it should show all tables.

Where I am having difficulty is that if I am on a house with a "garage" & "TV Room" only and I filter and check "study", I don't want to see an empty table labelled study - it should know it is hidden so not show it.

How do I do this? Cheers!

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" value = "study">Study</body>
        <input type="checkbox" value = "bedroom">Bedroom</body>
        <input type="checkbox" value = "kitchen">Kitchen</body>
        <input type="checkbox" value = "tv room">TV Room</body>
        <input type="checkbox" value = "garage">Garage</body>
        <table id = "study"></table>
        <table id = "bedroom"></table>
        <table id = "kitchen"></table>
        <table id = "tv room"></table>
        <table id = "garage"></table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Id can't have two words, `"tvroom"` instead of `"tv room"`

Comment: Please show your jQuery.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want a radio button.

Answer (score 3):

**js**

```
$("form input:checkbox").on("click",function(){
       var id = $(this).attr("value");
       if($(this).prop("checked"))
        $("#" + id).show();
       else
        $("#" + id).hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Set and id to your checkbox (checkBoxTvRoom) and try the following. Of course you'll have to code for the rest of the checkboxes as well :):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#checkBoxTvRoom').on('click',function(){
      if($(this).prop('checked') == 'checked')
      {
         $('#tvRoom').show();
      }else
      {
         $('#tvRoom').hide();
      }
   });
   //etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 checkboxes and you want "if the checkbox "study" is ticked, it would only show the study table". So you should make checkbox like radio button if you still using checkbox. Try this script

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
  var tableid = $(this).val();
  $("input[name='room'").prop("checked", false);
  $(this).prop("checked", true);
  $("table[data-name='room'").hide();
  $('#' + tableid).show(500);
);
```

demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fauzi/CXRpf/1/)